# Swiper - How center slides if the total slides width fit in the container width

Tags: javascript, slide, swiper.js

```
"swiper": "^4.2.6"
```

[Swiper demo](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/)

[Swiper repository](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/)

Hello,
I have this slider setup:

```
const options = {
      wrapperClass: 'slides-list',
      slideClass: 'slide',
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',  // Default slides per view
      spaceBetween: 20,
      loop: false,
      navigation: {
        prevEl: '.slider_btn--prev',
        nextEl: '.slider_btn--next'
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.slider_pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      speed: 300,
      on: {
        init: function () {
          console.log('swiper initialized');
        },
      }
    };
```

So i have this setup. *Black border for the slider wrapper, red border for the slides list*.

Works fine on mobile

[image]

But lets face the moment when all the slides width can fit into the slider wrapper, how can i centered then and maybe disable the drag option.

I dont know the slides widths, so right now in the example i have just 3 slides and this is the current behavior

[image]

And this one would be the desired one

[image]

I cannot use media queries because i dont know when the slides gonna fit in the container. so, Swiper has someway to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

> I dont want to use `slidesPerView: 3`, as i said, the point is to be
>   able to check all the slides that we have, then if all of them can fit
>   in the container, center them. Not to force X number of slides into
>   the view

Comment: If all fit into the container the slider will not have any purpose, yeah ? Then why use a slider ?

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan exactly, i need the slider until all fit the container, i'm asking for a way to do that when the slides number & width is unknown

Comment: Did you check on **Multiple Slides Per View** and **Centered Slides** in the demo page you have linked above.

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan i already have the centered slide property added at the top, and the slides per view is not what i want, because i dont know the width of the slides, i dont wanna show 3 or 4 per view, i want to show as many as possible, and if all can be shown, then center them.

Comment: @HéctorLeón – Wondering if you solves this issue. I'm looking for a smiliar solution, although I'm fine with setting `slidesPerView`, but still can't get to center all the slides, once they fit.

Comment: I was came with the same problem and ended choosing another plugin, slick.js. Swiper use CSS translate aproach, there is better for single slider not for carousel items, with slick you can do both.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript

```
const slider = new Swiper(element, {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  watchOverflow: true
});
    
slider.on('resize', function (instance) {
  element.classList.toggle('.slider-active', instance.virtualSize > instance.size);
});
```

CSS

```
.swiper-wrapper {
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider-active .swiper-wrapper {
  justify-content: normal;
}
```

This way you apply css to center the slides when te slide wrapper does not overflow the container. And visa versa to reset